# Who portrays Walter White in the scene where he and Gretchen establish the composition of the human body?

Tags: breaking-bad

In Breaking Bad, season 1, in relation to the dissolution of Emilio and Krazy-8's corpses, Walter and Gretchen are shown enumerating the various chemicals composing the human body. Supposedly it takes place a while back, and they appear younger, especially Walt. I had a strange feeling about Walt's facial expression and suspected it might not be Bryan Cranston. He is always shown in partial darkness, which could be to conceal either that Walt is portrayed by a different actor or that he is of course older than he is meant to appear.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they would have used Bryan Cranston ... I'm sure the lighting was to obscure their age and/or the makeup or cgi they used to de-age him a little.   I'm sure its easier to de-age / obscure age than use a different actor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no one else credited and I don't see any reason to think it was not Bryan Cranston. There is some obscurity due to the light coming in the window in the scene, but in my opinion it still looks very much like Bryan Cranston with some makeup to make him look younger. Note also that the actress portraying Gretchen is definitely the same actress that plays her older self.

[image]

Comment: I definitely agree about Gretchen. Wikipedia mentions no guests other than the ones we already know about, so you must be right about Cranston also.

Comment: I'd like to point out that CGI can be used to make an actor look younger. For example, CGI was applied to 40-year-old Patrick Dempsey to make him look 20 years old during some scenes of the movie _Made of Honor_. (I couldn't find a clip or images, unfortunately!)